# Variáveis de ambiente permanecerem

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

Estou seguindo [este](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation) tutorial, no Linux, mas toda vez que reinicio tenho que setar tudo de novo as variáveis

O que tenho que fazer para as configurações permanecerem e de forma global?

Estou usando o Linux Mint Cinamon (Sylvia) 64 bits

**[EDIT1]**

Por exemplo:

Eu faço isso no terminal, aí quando executo dentro do terminal do PhpStorm, o comando `tsc -w` por exemplo ele disse que: `/usr/bin/env: “node”: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado`, ai so seto as variaveis que funciona. Mas toda vez que quiser abrir uma nova janela de terminal tenho que setar novamente as variáveis de ambiente

Na verdade se eu usar o comando `~/.profile` dá essa mensagem `bash: /home/carlos/.profile: Permissão negada` tanto no root como no meu usuário

Comment: Explica melhor por favor, o **arquivo** `~/.profile` perde os dados, é isso?

Comment: Por exemplo, eu faço isso no terminal, aí quando executo dentro do terminal do PhpStorm, o comando `tsc -w` por exemplo ele disse que:
/usr/bin/env: “node”: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado, ai so seto as variaveis que funciona. Mas toda vez que quiser abrir uma nova janela de terminal tenho que setar novamente as variaveis de ambiente

Comment: Na verdade o comando `~/.profile` dá essa mensagem `bash: /home/carlos/.profile: Permissão negada`

Comment: @adventistaam Já tentou mover o node para `/usr/bin` ?

Comment: @adventistaam `~/.profile` não é um comando, é um arquivo, você tem que abrir ele por um processador de texto, como o Vim por exemplo, e adicionar as vars

Comment: Deu certo @GuilhermeNascimento essa sua última sugestão. Pode adicionar a resposta por favor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `~/.profile` citado no video não é um comando e por isto quando digita ocorre a mensagem:

> Permissão negada

Ele é um documento de configuração, ou seja você tem que editar ele com um processador de texto, como *Vim* por exemplo, então ao abrir no seu editor de texto na ultima linha (acaso já tenha algo nele) adicione isto (não apague nada):

```
export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.9.4/bin
export PATH=$NODEJS_HOME:$PATH
```

Então salve o documento, ao salvar ele talvez seja necessário fazer o refresh (ou então logoff), para fazer o refresh digite **exatamente** isto (incluindo o ponto no começo antes do caminho do arquivo):

```
. ~/.profile
```

No terminal vai parecer com algo como:

```
$. ~/.profile
```

Pronto deve funcionar, então para testar se teve efeito execute no terminal isto:

```
node -v
```